# How to get parent and child category items count?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am basically trying to make a category list which will have an array of categories and its subcategories.

My current query is:

```
SELECT category.lc_name AS name,COUNT(listings.ls_cat_id) AS post_count
FROM listings_categories AS category
LEFT JOIN listings ON listings.ls_cat_id = category.lc_id 
GROUP BY category.lc_id ORDER BY name ASC
```

It works pretty well however i want the subcategories items or posts count to be added to its parent category.

For example:

```
id | category | parent | Count
1      Auto        0       3
2      Auto A      1       1
3      Auto B      1       1
4      Auto C      1       1
```

What can i do this in mysql using only one query?

The Table Structure

```
listings - ls_id,ls_cat_id,ls_title
listings_categories - lc_id,lc_parent,lc_name
```

Comment: or could you create a sqlfiddle?

Comment: also, how 'deep' do subcategories go?  is it just 1 level?

Comment: Please have look to answer the same question.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/21959727/1915855

Answer (score 1):

ok, i've made a number of assumptions here, which may or may not be true and depend on your schema and data, but something like this should work:

```
select numListings, lc_name from
(
    SELECT
    IF(lc_parent = 0, lc_id, lc_parent) AS lc_parent_id, COUNT(ls_id) as numListings
    FROM listings_categories
    LEFT JOIN listings ON listings.ls_cat_id = listings_categories.lc_id
    group by lc_parent_id
) catList
inner join listings_categories on catList.lc_parent_id = listings_categories.lc_id;
```

this assumes:

- if a category has no parent, the lc_parent column value is 0
- there are only 2 levels of categories - ie. parents & children, no grandchildren
- you only want to show results for parent categories

let me know if any of these assumptions are incorrect and i can adjust the query.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the right answer.

```
SELECT category.lc_name AS name,

COUNT(listings.ls_cat_id) + (

    SELECT COUNT(listings.ls_cat_id) FROM listings_categories AS subcategory
    LEFT JOIN listings ON listings.ls_cat_id = subcategory.lc_id
    WHERE category.lc_id = subcategory.lc_parent
) AS count

FROM listings_categories AS category
LEFT JOIN listings ON listings.ls_cat_id = category.lc_id
GROUP BY category.lc_id ORDER BY name ASC
```

I just added the current count to another select statement that matches the current category id to new select statement's parent category id.

```
"name"  "count"
"auto detailing"    "0"
"auto insurance"    "1"
"auto mechanic" "1"
"auto painting" "0"
"auto sales and parts"  "0"
"automotive"    "3"
"business"  "0"
"dental clinics"    "0"
"fashion"   "0"
"health and medicine"   "0"
"health insurance"  "0"
"home and garden"   "0"
"hospital"  "0"
"jobs and employment"   "0"
```